# find next blank cell and autosum

Tags: excel, vba

I have data for same month in multiple columns in a continuous range.

Each month range is separated by a blank column.

What I want is a macro that find the next blank cell in column starting cell B10 and autosum the columns preceding the blank cell.

I want autosum in highlighted columns in yellow (must be a loop).

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt896.png)

I started writing the code but stuck:

```
Sub sum()

    ActiveSheet.Range("b10").Select

    Selection.Columns.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = "=Sum(columns.end (xltoleft)"

End Sub
```

Many thanks 
Sophia

Answer (score 0):

Variables

- x: Tracks the current row
- y: The first column in the range to be summed
- y1: The last column in the range to be summed

[image]

```
Sub AddColumnSums()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long, y1 As Long
    For x = 10 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" Then
            y = 2 ' Initialize the start column
            Do
                ' xlToRight brings you to the last cell in a continous cell block
                y1 = Cells(x, y).End(xlToRight).Column

                ' The formula is assigned the first cell after continous cell block

                Cells(x, y1 + 1).Formula = "=Sum(" & Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y1)).Address & ")"

                'The starting column is set to the first cell after the formula
                y = y1 + 2

            ' If there is no more data to the right of the starting column
            ' xlToRight will reference the last cell in the row and 
            ' the column loop will eixt

            Loop Until Cells(x, y).End(xlToRight).Column = Columns.Count
        End If
        'Increments to the next row
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Super !! Thanks. I am new to VBA so can you explain a bit more so I can tweak this if required

Comment: Many thanks Thomas. Couple more tweaks. How can I change the formula to sumif so it sum based on the column heading "Jan", "Feb" ........ Is there a way to declare these upfront and formula picks it up and sum these individually. Also can I put a column header in the total column for each month stating "Grand Total Jan", "Grand Total Feb"

Comment: Sorry that I overlooked your comment from Oct. 1st.  Do you want to create a summary table with fruit in column A and monthly labels running across columns B through M?  In any case, you should post a new question with screenshot of your setup with what you have tried and maybe a screenshot of the desired outcome.  I'm off tomorrow so I'm sure that I will see it.  But if you link me the new question I will respond.